# Restriction of a principal Weil divisor to an open subset is again principal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This post concerns Definition 7.2.12 of Liu's algebraic geometry:

> Let $X$ be an normal integral Noetherian scheme (though, Liu does not require this strongly, this is the assumption when I talk about Weil divisors). Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$. Let $Z$ be a Weil divisor, say, $$Z = \sum_{x \in X, \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = 1} n_x[\overline{x}]$$
> where only a finite number of $n_x$ is non-zero. Then, we can take the restriction of $Z$ to $U$:
> $$
> Z|_U = \sum_{x \in U, \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = 1}n_x[\overline{x}]
> $$
> If $f \in K(X)^*$, the function field of $X$, then
> $$(f)|_U = (f|_U)$$
> where $(f)$ is the principal Weil divisor associated to $f$, i.e.,
> $$
> (f) = \sum_{x \in X, \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = 1} v_x(f)[\overline{x}]
> $$
> where $v_x : \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the discrete valuation on $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$

**The question is:** How to show $(f)|_U = (f|_U)$? Actually, the question is in two parts.

1. I have a doubt on the symbol $f|_U$: $f|_U$ should mean the restriction of $f$ to $U$ in the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. But, by definition, $f \in K(X)$, how is it guaranteed that $f \in \mathcal{O}(V)$ for some open subset $V \supset U$.
2. Suppose we have solved 1), let's say $f \in K(X)^*$ verifying $g = f|_U \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$.
   How to show that $g \in \mathcal{O}_{X,y}^*$ for $y \notin U$ of codimension $1$, so that $v_y(g) = 0$.

Can any one help me on this? Thank you.